# Сборка ng build --prod после команды ng eject

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angular2, angular4, angular5

На Angular5 проекте с помощью ng eject был сгенерирован файл `webpack.config.json` который был сконфижен/обновлен под конкретные задачи.
Соответственно, изменились команды запуска/сборки:

```
ng serve --> npm start
ng build --> npm run build
```

На сборке нужно максимальное сжатие, которое можно получить командой 
ng build --prod, но т.к был сделан eject webpack.config.json данная команда не проходит. Сборка командой ng build сжимает недостаточно.

Есть ли какой-то аналог этой этой команды:

```
npm run build --prod
```

Можно конечно удалить `webpack.config.json` и запустить `ng build --prod`, но при этом (я так думаю) собьются все внесенные в webpack кастомные настойки.

Как сделать максимальное сжатие продакшн файла и не удалять конфиг вебпака?

Comment: Для этого надо посмотреть, как выглядит извлеченный `webpack.config.json` и на что там влияет ключ `--prod`. Скорее всего надо будет передать соответствующий ключ в `npm run build`.

Comment: npm run build --prod не проходит, ошибка

Comment: Скидывайте конфиг вебпака. Надо смотреть, на что влияет ключ `--prod` Может быть ключ `--prod` просто устанавливает `mode = 'production'`.